# downloaded files going to my root directory

Tags: php, directory

I am currently building a video downloading tool using PHP. The videos are downloading without any issue by selecting the path you want but I always get a copy of the video in my root directory.

I am using the following `function` to download the files:

```
        function df($urlFile){

            $file_name  =   basename("download.png");
            //save the file by using base name
            $fn =   file_put_contents($file_name,file_get_contents($urlFile));
            header("Expires: 0");
            header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s")." GMT");
            header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
            header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
            header("Pragma: no-cache");
            header("Content-type: image/jpg");
            header('Content-length: '.filesize($file_name));
            header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file_name).'"');
            readfile($file_name);
        }   
    
        df($main_url);    `
    
df($main_url);
```

Can you please help to avoid the files from being saved in my directory?

I only want the videos to download normally in the path the users want and not a copy in the root directory

Comment: Well `file_put_contents` is saving the file to your server, obviously.  Strictly you don't need to do that...you could just use `file_get_contents` to put the file contents into a variable in-memory, and then just `echo` that variable directly to the client (in place of readFile)

Comment: @ADyson OK but can you please write it? Because I am trying but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

This line is doing the saving:

```
$fn =   file_put_contents($file_name,file_get_contents($urlFile));
```

The `file_get_contents($urlFile)` part is loading the file and you could simply assign it to a variable, like this:

```
$myContent = file_get_contents($urlFile);
```

then you can do what you please with this content.